# How can I find the session Id when using express / connect and a session store?

Tags: node.js, redis, express

If a user is already logged in and tries to login again in a new instance I'd like it to log out the other user instance. I don't want the same user to be logged in twice on my application.

Currently the session is stored in a Redis store, i'm using express / connect to handle the session storage. One of the functions available which could be used to destroy the session is as follows:

```
.destroy(sid, callback)
```

However I need to find that session id before I call .destroy(). In Redis the username is stored as a part of the session.

**Question: Is it possible to query Redis to obtain the session id based on the username?**

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`req.sessionID` will provide you the session's ID, where req is a request object.

Comment: Why this isn't the accepted answer?
Works great for me. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't working for me. `req.sessionID` is `undefined`. NodeJS 9.x, express 4, express-session 1.15.

Comment: Use req.session.id

Answer (score 29):

For recent readers;

Connect middlewares are not included in Express since version 4.

So in order to have `req.sessionID` work you must do following:

1. Make sure you have `cookie-parser` abd `express-session` modules inside your package.json. If it's not added, add them:

> ```
> npm install express-session --save
> npm install cookie-parser --save
> ```

2. Be careful about the order while requiring them in your `app.js` file and add required configuration parameters.

> ```
> var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
> var session = require('express-session')
> app.use(cookieParser());
> app.use(session({
>     secret: '34SDgsdgspxxxxxxxdfsG', // just a long random string
>     resave: false,
>     saveUninitialized: true
> }));
> ```

3. Now you should be using [`req.sessionID`](https://github.com/expressjs/session?_ga=1.252791050.2089850976.1448301229#reqsessionid) and [`req.session.id`](https://github.com/expressjs/session?_ga=1.252791050.2089850976.1448301229#reqsessionid).

Comment: cookie-parser was deprecated for express-session back at 1.5.0 (see readme at https://github.com/expressjs/session). In fact, cookie-parser can now cause side-effects.

Answer (score 17):

Store the SID with the account, when the user logs in during the database validation of the user account call .destroy(sid, fn), then update the SID in the database with the current SID of the user.

In my case using MongoDB this is how i've done it:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res)
{
  var sid = req.sessionID;
  var username = req.body.user;
  var password = req.body.pass;

  users.findOne({username : username, password : password}, function(err, result)
  { 
    ...
    sessionStore.destroy(result.session, function(){
       ...
       users.update({_id: result._id}, {$set:{"session" : sid}});
       ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is it possible to query Redis to obtain the session id based on the username?

No. The session keys in redis are not named after the username.

Here's a thought, though: When an already logged in user tries to login again, can't you see that, in your application, and either destroy the old session immediately, or not allow them to login again?